# 3d picking from arbitrary viewpoint

Tags: opengl, graphics

I created a 3d scene of many pipes (valves,manhole) of different colors and materials . Now I want to use the mouse to pick them and get their attributes(color,material). I've tried to use glupushmatrix, the method provided by OpenGL API ,it worked when the viewpoint is almost right in front of the pipe.But when looking from different viewpoints ,such as from (0,1,1) to (0,0,0),it can't do it. What's more , I didn't find any projection settings for functions glulookat before glupushmatrix . I also tried to use ray tracing based picking using math , but I found it is difficult to do intersection testing for each pipe using brute force .

Comment: First of all, `gluPushMatrix` is not a part of OpenGL spec. Secondly, ray *casting* (which is different from tracing) is easy enough, even with the "brute force" method you suggested and with reasonable number of shapes and some broadphase culling (AABBs should do) should "be enough for everyone". That being said, show the code used for color-based picking, because right now all we know is that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL provide a special render mode ([`GL_SELECT`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glRenderMode.xml)) to help achieving picking.

To implement it you have to:

- [Name](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushName.xml) your selectable primitives
- Add a rendering pass with `GL_SELECT` mode.

*edited the link:*

Follow [this tutorial...](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~mjb/cs553/Handouts/Picking/picking.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your attention. In fact ,i used the same technique . I followed the [tutorial link](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/) It worked when the you are right in front of the object(just like the snowman examples). But when you view from other angle,such as a bird eye's view, it failed. I didn't know whether it is the limitation of this method or   there are problems with my program.

Comment: @Leoxu: I've used this technique in a 3d landscape and it works well. Show maybe your code. Drawing order is overriding depth test in selection mode if I remember...

Comment: @Leoxu: Your tuto miss a [`glutPickMatrix`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPickMatrix.xml) example. It's a helper to set the correct matrix for picking.

Comment: There are several articles included in the tutorial,just go to the bottom ,you can see "next". I used the same picking code , changes are just made in draw part ,pushing name before drawing the object and popping it the after,for both mode RENDER and SELECT,i use the same code. Here is the [picture...](https://www.flickr.com/photos/124138734@N08/) to illustrate the problem...

Comment: @Leoxu: You may render with your pick matrix (extending width/height) to check it.